# Cannot Resolve Constructor 'Order(Java.lang.string,Java.lang.string,Java.lang.string,void,void)

Tags: android, constructor-injection

For my android project, most data are save from database and my app will fetch it. However, I have two dialog box that will set dates to two text views and then save it to my database. I'm trying to use currentBeach.setCheckIn(checkInTV.getText().toString()) which causes my program to have an error on constructor. What is the solution for here?

**Details.java**

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Database(getBaseContext()).addToCart(new Order(
                    menuID,
                    currentBeach.getName(),
                    currentBeach.getPrice(),
                    currentBeach.setCheckIn(checkInTV.getText().toString()),
                    currentBeach.setCheckOut(checkOutTV.getText().toString())
            ));
            Intent intent = new Intent(details.this, Cart.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

**Order.Java (Constructor)**

```
public Order(String productId, String productName, String description, String price, String checkIn, String checkOut) {
    ProductId = productId;
    ProductName = productName;
    Description = description;
    Price = price;
    this.checkIn = checkIn;
    this.checkOut = checkOut;
}
```

Help me please. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not passing the `description` as argument  in `Order` constructor

Your `Order` constructor  has 6 arguments while you are passing 5 arguments inside `btnSubmit.setOnClickListener()` check it

Another issue was`currentBeach.setCheckIn(checkInTV.getText().toString())` and `currentBeach.setCheckOut(checkOutTV.getText().toString()` this method returning **void** while you need to pass `String` value in `Order` constructor

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Database(getBaseContext()).addToCart(new Order(
                    menuID,
                    currentBeach.getName(),
                   "description",// pass descriptiion here
                    currentBeach.getPrice(),
                    checkInTV.getText().toString(),
                    checkOutTV.getText().toString())
            ));
            Intent intent = new Intent(details.this, Cart.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: the problem is actually not that but on the currentBeach.setCheckIn(checkInTV.getText().toString()) and currentBeach.setCheckOut(checkOutTV.getText().toString()). it says void, void

Comment: That solves the problem but let me try on my emulator first and check if it saves to my database. Thanks much.